# Parse Sign up Segment controller Issue

Tags: ios, swift

I have added Segment controller in Sign up view controller but I can't detect which button pressed to send the data to parse.com.

The issue in this code:

```
var user = PFUser()
user.username = username.text
user.password = password.text
user[Gender] = gender.selectedSegmentIndex
// The Issue here
// gender is a Segment controller
```

I want to detect which button chosen and send the title of the chosen button to the parse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the text associated with a specific index, try

```
let genderString = gender.titleForSegmentAtIndex(gender.selectedSegmentIndex)
```

Comment: was about to say this :P

Comment: Thank you for your help!, i did what you said and then i wrote this: user["Gender"] = genderString  , but i got this output when i signup: Invalid type for key Gender, expected boolean, but got string  , please help!

Comment: Well I think you just answered your own question. Parse is telling you that your "_User" class has a field named "Gender" but it's set as a bool, and not as a string, yet you're passing it the text value of the `segmentedControl`. So either switch on the text and say male is false and female is true (which I wouldn't reccommend because that doesn't make sense) or change your gender field in Parse to be a field of strings instead of booleans.

Comment: Thank you so much! i've changed the Gender from the parse to String and worked! I hope you'll get a happy day! really appreciate it

Comment: Of course, glad to help! If you could please accept my answer, that would be great :)